# Moving files in Bazel

Tags: c++, ubuntu, bazel

I'm using bazel(0.22 version) on ubuntu 18.04 for building a C++ code.

main.cpp has an api to read the ui file which reads the ui file.

Api looks like below

```
auto ui_data = readUIData("Front_end.ui");
```

I'm able to build the code. But since the "Front_end.ui" file always resides in ui/Front_end.ui path in bin folder and exe is outside of the "ui" folder above given c++ code snippets fails.

Following is the BUILD file snippet

```
cc_binary(
name = "UI_exe",
srcs = ["bin/main.cpp"],
data = ["ui/Front_end.ui"],
)
```

Following is the directory structure.

[Folder directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbyxJ.png)

Comment: Don't use relative paths. You should not be making any assumptions about the location of files relative to your current working directory, ever. (E.g. it's none of your business whether the user says `/tmp/a.out` or `(cd /tmp && ./a.out)`.) Make the path configurable and pass it in as a command line flag.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Thanks for the input. But is there a workaround for this without modifying the code in main.cpp

Comment: As I said, no such thing makes sense. You don't control how your executable is run. It's completely misguided to bake any such assumption into your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

To copy the data file to the same directory as the binary, you can use a genrule:

```
genrule(
    name = "copy",
    srcs = ["ui/Front_end.ui"],
    outs = ["Front_end.ui"],
    output_to_bindir = 1,
    cmd = "cp $< $@",
)
```

Since there's only one `srcs` and one `outs` entry, you can use `$<` and `$@` respectively.

(Otherwise you'd have to use `$(location ...)` expressions. Bazel replaces those with the actual path of the files, whatever that path may be at time of the build.)

---

You need to use the [C++ runfiles library](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/3dbf778af034b10005c42732e079ec309c87d350/tools/cpp/runfiles/runfiles_src.h#L15). Documentation is there in the source file.

Once you initialized the `std::unique_ptr<Runfiles> runfiles`, you can look up the file's runtime path like so:

```
std::string path = runfiles->Rlocation("my_workspace/my_package_path/ui/Front_end.ui");
```

You have to replace `my_workspace` with the name of your workspace, and `my_package_path` with the package path of the binary.

#### Workspace name

If for example the `WORKSPACE` file contains `workspace(name = "foo")` then `my_workspace` should be `foo`. If there's no such rule in the `WORKSPACE` file, then use the default workspace name: `__main__`.

#### Package path

This is the workspace-root-relative path to the BUILD file where you defined the cc_binary, e.g. "app/BUILD" in your example. So `my_package_path` should be just `app`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But i don't want to disturb the main.cpp. Instead i want to find a way in bazel to get exe and the "Front_end.ui" to same path in bin folder.

Comment: the reason for not making changes to the code is because, this project is built using bazel(by some user) and as well as cmake(by others).

Comment: but here we are creating a new output folder named "out" right and then copying the .exe and .ui files there. Is a way to only move the .ui to be in .exe file path.

Comment: Yes it's possible, I updated the `genrule` to do that.

Comment: Thanks this is what i was exactly looking for. This solved the problem!!! Thanks Laszlo :)